# Compare element in array and loop through each php

Tags: php, loops, compare, match

I want to compare a value of data to a list of element which I had retrieved from php array(decoded json).

First,

This is the first array:

```
Array1
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [member_id] => 3
        [member_card_num] => 2013011192330791
        [member_barcode] => 2300067628912
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [member_id] => 4
        [member_card_num] => 2328482492740000
        [member_barcode] => 3545637000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [member_id] => 2
        [member_card_num] => 40001974318
        [member_barcode] => 486126
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [member_id] => 1
        [member_card_num] => 91001310000057698
        [member_barcode] => 000057698
    )
```

)

This is the second Array:

```
Array2
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [member_id] => 2
        [member_card_num] => 40001974318
        [member_barcode] => 486126
    )
```

)

Second,

I had retrieved the (member_barcode) which I required.

Here is the code:

For Array1:

```
 foreach ($decode1 as $d){

        $merchant_barcode = $d ['member_barcode']; 
        echo  $merchant_barcode;

     }
```

For Array2:

```
 foreach ($decode2 as $d2){
      $user_barcode = $d2 ['member_barcode'];
      echo $user_barcode;
     }
```

Then, 
I get this output():

For Array1(merchant_barcode):

```
2300067628912
3545637000
486126
000057698
```

For Array2(user_barcode):

```
486126
```

**The question is, I would to check and compare whether the user_barcode in Array2(486126) is exist/match to one of the merchant_barcode in Array1.**

This is my code, 
but it only compare the user_barcode in Array2 to the last element(000057698) in Array1,

I want it to loop through each n check one by one. How can I do that?

```
public function actionCompareBarcode($user_barcode, $merchant_barcode){

      if(($user_barcode) == ($merchant_barcode)){
            echo "barcode exist. ";

        }

     else{

         echo "barcode not exist";
     }
  }
```

In this case, the output I get is "barcode not exist", but it should be "barcode exist".
Anyone can help? Appreciate that. Im kinda new to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested loop like:

```
foreach ($decode2 as $d2)
{
      $user_barcode = $d2 ['member_barcode'];
      foreach ($decode1 as $d)
      {
        $merchant_barcode = $d ['member_barcode']; 
        if ($merchant_barcode == $user_barcode)
        {
            echo "Match found!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No match found!";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?

$a = array(
        array(
                'member_id' => 3,
                'member_card_num' => '2013011192330791',
                'member_barcode' => '2300067628912',
        ),
        array(
                'member_id' => 4,
                'member_card_num' => '2328482492740000',
                'member_barcode' => '3545637000',
        ),
        array(
                'member_id' => 2,
                'member_card_num' => '40001974318',
                'member_barcode' => '486126',
        ),
        array(
                'member_id' => 1,
                'member_card_num' => '91001310000057698',
                'member_barcode' => '000057698',
        )
);

$b = array(
        array(
                'member_id' => 2,
                'member_card_num' => '40001974318',
                'member_barcode' => '486126',
        )
);


array_walk($a, function($item) use($b) {
    echo ($b['0']['member_barcode'] == $item['member_barcode'] ? "found" : NULL);
});

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) to calculate if those multidimensional arrays have a common element:

```
<?php
$a = array(
  array(
    'member_id' => '3',
    'member_card_num' => '2013011192330791',
    'member_barcode' => '2300067628912',
  ),
  array(
    'member_id' => '2',
    'member_card_num' => '40001974318',
    'member_barcode' => '486126',
  )
);

$b = array(
  array(
    'member_id' => '2',
    'member_card_num' => '40001974318',
    'member_barcode' => '486126',
  )
);

$match = array_uintersect($a, $b, function($valueA, $valueB) {
    return strcasecmp($valueA['member_barcode'], $valueB['member_barcode']);
});

print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling that method as you are looping through Array1 and comparing the user_barcode to every value

Answer (score 0):

**You can compare two array this way too:**

```
$per_arr = array();
$permissions = array()
foreach ($per_arr as $key => $perms) {
    if(isset($permissions[$key]['name'])){
        echo  $per_arr[$key]['name']; //matched data
    }else{
        echo $per_arr[$key]['name']; //not matched data
    }
}
```